# SQL Fulltext search column contained in a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, containstable

We added a fulltext search on 'name' and the following query is working fine:

`select * from products where contains( name, 'milk')`

But we couldn't find a way to run the reversed version:

`select * from products where contains( 'milk', name)`

Is there a way to find all the names contained in 'milk'?

Comment: select * from products where name like '%milk%'

Comment: @AbdulRasheed that search won't fly it won't use the free-text but run a full table scan

Comment: Isn't that the same as `name = 'milk'`?

Comment: Are you asking if it is somehow possible for SQL Server to have a full-text index of a string constant that is created at query time?

Comment: No, but perhaps there's a way to optimize such query using free text search